# iphone app and Facebook like button integration

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

Can anyone tell me a good tutorial that works for the new Graph API Facebook SDK.

I have tried the Facebook tutorial and it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth2-graph-api). But a word of advice; as much as it might seem the easier thing to do is to follow a tutorial on how someone shoehorned some language/API into working with another service, it is nearly always better to actually read the documentation of that service and understand how it works, what technologies it uses, what errors mean, the future status of API technologies (ie, depreciated ones vs reliable ones), etc, etc. As much as I hated the twitter API when I first started reading it - and switched focus to using a wrapper like MGTwitterEngine - I never really understood it (and paradigms like REST/JSON) until I sat down and perused the API.

Comment: couldn't agree more! however I found a tutorial that made my day. thanks!